# Java: how to move the contents of a multidimentional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a small project. I'm writing a simple java program for the L game. I need to write a method that will move the content of a `4x4` array. This method will take in `(row, column)` parameters. and the contents will move accordingly.

```
{ 'x',' ',' ',' ' }, 

{ 'x',' ',' ',' ' },

{ 'x','x',' ',' ' },

{ ' ',' ',' ',' ' }
```

move (0, 2)
--->

```
{ ' ',' ','x',' ' },

{ ' ',' ','x',' ' },

{ ' ',' ','x','x' },

{ ' ',' ',' ',' ' }
```

I'm not sure where to start. I really appreciate any help given on this. 
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Start by doing this for a standard 1D array. From there it's easy, just loop through each 1D array in your 2D array.

Comment: You sure the expected outcome for `(0, 2)` will turn out like that?!

Comment: Create a new two-dimensional array, put in it the data from the first array, with an offset corresponding to the (row, column) parameters. Try something and if you hit a wall, come to tell us.

Comment: is the movement circular? i.e.  if someone pass the value (1,3) then 2nd column elements should come to first column or should lost.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to write any code?

Comment: The least you can do is 'try' and then come back if you hit a brick wall. Posting a problem as it is not going to help the learning cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method should look something like this

```
char[][] array = new char[4][4];

public static void move(row, column){
    for (int i = 0, i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (array[i][j] != null) {
                // add rows and column accordingly
                array[i + row][j + column] = array[i][j];
                array[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is considering there is only one `x` per line, which in your case, some lines have two.  I'll let you figure that one out.

Comment: Another user asked the same question for what they termed their "assignment" (presumably homework). You may want to hold off on the code if they ask for any more help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532403/copying-a-2d-non-space-array-to-another

Comment: He removed the question. I still don't have an the correct answer that I want yet. Any chance you could help?

Comment: What do you need help with? Also, put you code at the bottom of your post.  And explain in detail exactly where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int moverow = 0;
    int moveCol = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i <=3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <=3; j++){
            int currentValue = board[i][j];
            //shifting value
            int shiftX = i + moverow;
            int shiftY = j + moveCol;
            // discarding the value if index overflows
            if(shiftX > 3 || shiftY > 3){

                // setting initial value on the original index.
                board[i][j] = 0;
                break;
            }else{
                board[shiftX][shiftY] = currentValue;
                // setting initial value on the original index.
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```